# MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra: how to append a Vector to another quickly?

Tags: c#, matlab

I'm converting an algorithm from Matlab to C#.

At a certain point, there's this new vector in the matlab code:

```
F = [D * z + v; m1 + rgb];
```

`D` is a 36x36 matrix, `z` and `v` are 36x1 vectors, `m1` and `rgb` are 3x1 vectors. This means that `F` is a 39x1 vector.

Now, when converting this code to C# using MathNet, I found out that, apparently, there's no append function, and the best that I could come to is this code:

```cs
var F = Vector<float>.Build.Dense(39);
var firstElements = Vector<float>.Build.Dense(36);
var lastElements = Vector<float>.Build.Dense(3);
firstElements = D * z + v;
lastElements = m1 + rgb;
firstElements.CopySubVectorTo(F, 0, 0, firstElements.Count);
lastElements.CopySubVectorTo(F, 0, firstElements.Count, lastElements.Count);
```

Is there a quicker way to create the `F` vector?

Comment: There is an Add method, though.

Comment: @TaW yes, but, if I'm not mistaken,  `Add` is used to sum the values of elements of vectors (or a scalar to the elements of a single vector), not to add new elements to a pre-existing vector.

Comment: Ah, right, sorry..

Answer (score 2):

Not especially pretty, but this would work:

```
F = firstElements.ToColumnMatrix().Stack(lastElements.ToColumnMatrix()).Column(0);
```

It would probably be a good feature to add, a function to Stack 2 vectors.